# How to make c++_static stl work fine in Android Studio when I use unordered_map

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Every time I call the method find,begin,end.It make a error promt that there are multiple implementations or no matching definition.Howerver,it's ok to compile at all.Why can it distinguish iterator from const_iterator of std::vector but not std::unordered_map and std::map.
It works fine with gnu_stl before ndk_r17-rc1. However,it says that gnu_stl will no longer be supported, and operator== and operator!= can't be resolved anymore since ndk_r17-rc1 by the ide.
Yeah,it's always fine to compile.
My Android Studio version is 3.1.0 rc1

Answer (score 0):

aiui the CLion (the C++ IDE that Studio is based on) parser does not understand SFINAE, which means it can't deal with the STL. There's a fix coming for this, but probably not until 3.2 since it's only just recently been fixed and 3.1 is being finalized.